# Destructuring nullable objects

Tags: typescript, object, ecmascript-6

Typescript (or should we say ES) doesn't allow destructuring of null/undefined objects. It throws TypeError.

So, lets say we have something like

```
let {a,b,c} = D;
```

where `D` could be `null`.

If we need to do conditional destructuring assignment with null-checks then we create boilerplate code for something that was meant to reduce it.

What is the most elegant way of using it in cases like that or should we use destructuring only for guaranteed non-null objects?

Comment: and Typescript does a good job in doing so. Instead of bypassing the type system you should embrace its objectives, which is among other things: Know your types.

Comment: could you please be a bit more explicit? some example? how is type system related to this particular problem? (i am familiar with static typing)

Comment: With a static type system you should know the types of all your variables. The type of a variable must not change during runtime. I don't know how fancy Typescript's type system is, but at least you should know whether `D` is `null` or an `Object` type.

Comment: wait wait...but Object can be nullable. What then?

Answer (score 192, accepted):

You can use an empty object as fallback, and if `D` is `null` or `undefined` the assigned variables will be `undefined`.

```js
const D = null;
const { a, b, c } = D || {};

console.log(a, b, c);
```

Using typescript you need to add the correct type (or `any`) to the FALLBACK object ([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWyDeAoZQ5OAfgC5kBnMKUAcwG4Cj1yqb6mjkE3raQjPAF88eBAHsQ1ZABFkAXmQgArgBs1TSdLC5iAGmTpDCZMMVzkAHyu5zcSmixNxUyhLUQAdGol0AFHCGxjwAlAxAA)). For example:

```
interface Obj {
    a?: string;
    b?: string;
    c?: string;
}

const D = null;
const { a, b, c } = D || {} as Obj;

console.log(a, b, c);
```

Another option is to use [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals), since spreading `null` or `undefined` results in an empty object ([see this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47156824/5157454)).

```js
const D = null;
const { a, b, c } = { ...D };

console.log(a, b, c);
```

Using typescript you need to add the types to the variable that you spread, and the object that you destructure. For example ([TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWyDeAoZQ5OAfgC5kBnMKUAcwG4Cj1yqb6mjkE3raQjPAF88eBAHsQ1ZABFkAXmQgArgBs1TSdLC5iAGmTpDCZMMV6AdNflxKxEAE8zxexkxNxUyhLURLahJ0ABRwhsY8AJQMQA)):

```
interface Obj {
    a?: string;
    b?: string;
    c?: string;
}

const D = null;
const { a, b, c } = { ...D as any } as Obj;

console.log(a, b, c);
```

If you need to handle nested destructuring, use defaults:

```js
const D = null;
const { a, a: { z } = {}, b, c } = { ...D };

console.log(a, b, c, z);
```

Comment: Any ideas about how to do this well in a sub-object? eg:
```
let a = { b: null };
let { b: { c } } = a; // Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target
```

Comment: How about nested restructuring? e.g. `const { z: { b } } = a;` in this case, `z` is undefined

Comment: These options don't work with TypeScript.

Comment: I don't know if something about strict type checking changed in Typescript since this answer was posted but as @Organic mentioned these solutions don't work in Typescript currently. When I try to destructure an empty object like this `const { a, b, c } = D || {};` I get an error `Property 'a' does not exist on type '{}'`.

Comment: @Dado - Both options work with TS as long as you the add correct types. I've added examples for TS + links to TS Playground.