# Spreading undefined in array vs object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

Why does spreading undefined in an object return an empty object? `{...undefined} // equals {}`:

```js
console.log({...undefined})
```

And Why does spreading undefined in an array give you an error?
`[...undefined] // type error`:

```js
console.log([...undefined])
```

Comment: https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/687

Comment: To summarize: object spread is equivalent to `Object.assign` whereas array spread is actually iterable spread and `undefined` isn't iterable.

Comment: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread/issues/45

Comment: This is also a good discussion: https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/pull/1069

Comment: Also `...null` and `...false` seem to behave the same?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

As noted in the comments, and summarized by @ftor from [#687](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/687), object spread is equivalent<sup>1</sup> to [Object.assign()](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.assign) (issues [#687](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/687), [#45](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread/issues/45)), whereas spread in array literal context is iterable spread.

Quoting [Ecma-262 6.0](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html), [Object.assign()](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.assign) is defined as:

> #### 19.1.2.1 Object.assign ( target, ...sources )
>
> The **assign** function is used to copy the values of all of the enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. When the **assign** function is called, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let to be [ToObject](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-toobject)(target).
> 2. [ReturnIfAbrupt](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-returnifabrupt)(to).
> 3. If only one argument was passed, return to.
> 4. Let sources be the [List](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-list-and-record-specification-type) of argument values starting with the second argument.
> 5. For each element nextSource of sources, in ascending index order, do
>
>    1. If nextSource is **undefined** or **null**, let keys be an empty [List](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-list-and-record-specification-type).
>    2. Else, ...

...followed by the description of copying own properties. The draft of Object Rest/Spread Properties is [here](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-object-rest-spread/). It is not a part of the Ecma-262 6.0.

A [*SpreadElement*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-runtime-semantics-arrayaccumulation) in an array literal expression is defined to begin as follows:

> *SpreadElement* : **...** *AssignmentExpression*
>
> 1. Let *spreadRef* be the result of evaluating *AssignmentExpression*.
> 2. Let *spreadObj* be [GetValue](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-getvalue)(*spreadRef*).
> 3. Let *iterator* be [GetIterator](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-getiterator)(*spreadObj*).
> 4. [ReturnIfAbrupt](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-returnifabrupt)(iterator).

And since [`undefined`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-undefined-value) does not have a property with the key [@@iterator](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-well-known-symbols), a **TypeError** is thrown, based on the steps of [GetIterator](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-getiterator). The standard is not an easy read, but if I'm not mistaken, the path to error is [GetIterator](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-getiterator) -> [GetMethod](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-getmethod) -> [GetV](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-getv) -> [ToObject](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-toobject), which throws a TypeError for undefined and null.

A simple remedy to using variables with possibly undefined value in array initialization is to use a default:

```
const maybeArray = undefined;
const newArray = [ ...(maybeArray || []) ];
```

---

<sup>1</sup>: There is a difference in [how setters are handled](https://css-tricks.com/new-es2018-features-every-javascript-developer-should-know/#article-header-id-0).

Comment: Since `undefined` and `null` are treated as an empty enumerable, why aren't they also treated as an empty iterable?

Comment: You can find discussion about that in https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/687.

Answer (score 18):

Normally, uses of `...x` requires `x` to be *iterable* because the point of `...` is normally to flatten an iterable into its components. An array is a prime example of an iterable.

`undefined` is not *iterable*. It has no components, so it doesn't make sense to iterate over `undefined`. `[...undefined]` therefore fails. `for (const e of undefined)` similarly fails, since `of` also requires an *iterable*.

However, `{...x}`  requires `x` to be *enumerable* because it needs not just values, but keys along with them. An object is a prime example of an enumerable.

`undefined` is *enumerable*. `undefined` is sometime treated as an object, and this is one of those cases. Objects are enumerable because they can have properties. `{...undefined}` therefore succeeds. `for (const p in undefined)` similarly succeeds, since `in` requires an *enumerable*.

---

**A note about `null`**

A question asking about `null`'s behaviour as an operand of `...` was closed as a duplicate of this question. While `null` and `undefined` have distinct types, the above answers applies equally to `null`.

Comment: Since `undefined` and `null` are treated as an empty enumerable, why aren't they also treated as an empty iterable?

Comment: @Géry Ogam, Are they? Or are they treated like objects (which aren't normally iterable).

Comment: In the accepted answer, the quoted standard asserts ‘If nextSource is undefined or null, let keys be an empty List.’ so they behave like the empty object in the context of object spread. But I don't see what would prevent them from behaving like empty lists in other contexts like array spread. Restricting their polymorphism creates an inconsistency that surprises developers.

Comment: @Géry Ogam, Re "*Restricting their polymorphism creates an inconsistency*", An inconsistency with what? It's currently consistent with objects. With what would `undefined` become consistent if it was both iterable and enumerable? Anyway, my earlier question was rhetorical, pointing out that your point of view was purely subjective. And also completely off-topic. This is not the place the start a debate as to how this should have been designed. (If it was, I'd question why `undefined` is enumerable at all.)

Comment: Okay you can argue that `undefined` and `null` behave like an empty object in this context so it’s consistent that they don’t behave like an empty array in another context. But that’s not developers’ expectation as the number of likes of the question shows, so there is clearly a language issue. `undefined` and `null` represent emptiness *without a specific type*, they don't represent only empty *objects*, so they should be usable in any contexts where an empty value is accepted. That's what developers expect.

Comment: @Géry Ogam, Re "*But that’s not developers’ expectation as the number of likes of the question shows*", huh? That's a mighty bold claim! /// Re "*undefined and null represent emptiness*", Hell no! They are an exceptional value, but not necessarily emptiness. /// Re "*That's what developers expect.*" Not really! I would expect an error.

Comment: Re "*Okay you can argue*", That's my point. One can argue.  That's the answer to your question. Now please stop. You were answered three times now. This is not a place for debate.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this expression: `[...(this.options || [])]`, where options is an array.

Comment: This in no way answers the question. not having sufficient permissions to post comments is not an excuse for posting it as an answer.