# Why does JavaScript's spread syntax allow {...null} but not [...null]?

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax

Was updating a bit of code today that returns optional props to a React component. I discovered that even though the function sometimes returns `null`, it wouldn't error when the return value was immediately unpacked.

Pedantic summary of the code:

```
const returnPropsOrDont = (condition) => {
  if (condition) return null;
  return { optionalProp: 'foo' };
}
...
render() {
  const { condition } = props;
  return <SomeComponent
           staticProp="staticProp"
           {...returnPropsOrDont(condition)}
         />
}
```

Upon realizing this was cool, I ran to the console and tried it out on Objects and Arrays. Alas -

```
   > {...null} // {}
   > {...undefined} // {}, which is interesting because null is an object but undefined is not
   > [...null] // Uncaught TypeError: object null is not iterable
```

I did some light Googling and [found one article](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3590-you-can-safely-apply-object-spread-to-null-and-undefined-values-in-typescript-3-2-4.htm) which suggests that TypeScript considers it a feature to make sure optionally defined values don't haunt an unsuspecting developer. Fine, but a) I'm not using TypeScript, and b) I have no idea why JS wouldn't guard Arrays in the same way.

Since this does seem like a guard against optionally defined values, why is `{...null}` fine and `[...null]` not?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov then it really shouldn't work with `undefined`, right? but it does

Comment: *"which is interesting because null is an object but undefined is not"* `null` is not an object either. `typeof` isn't great in that aspect.

Comment: See this discussion: https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/687

Comment: Even better one: https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/pull/1069

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Normally, uses of `...x` requires `x` to be *iterable* because the point of `...` is normally to flatten an iterable into its components. An array is a prime example of an iterable.

`null` is not *iterable*. It has no components, so it doesn't make sense to iterate over `null`. `for (const e of null)` will similarly fail, since `of` also requires an *iterable*.

However, `{...x}`  requires `x` to be *enumerable* because it needs not just values, but keys along with them. An object is a prime example of an enumerable.

`null` is *enumerable*. `null` is sometime treated as an object, and this is one of those cases. Objects are enumerable because they can have properties. `for (const p in null)` will similarly succeed, since `in` requires an *enumerable*.

Comment: Yeah, I think I was misled by the seemingly overloaded `...` operator and the subsequent article I found didn't help by declaring it a 'feature', making the use with an Array look like an oversight.

Comment: `null` is not an object. It does not have properties (not even an empty list of properties). Try `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(null)`.

Comment: @ikegami: Yes, [but `typeof` is weird](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#table-35b). [`null` is its own data type](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-null-type).

Comment: @Felix King, Ok, I tweaked the wording.

Answer (score 3):

[…null] - here you use spear operator and it works only for iterable objects (like strings, arrays, generators or custom iterable objects), but null isn't iterable object and will recieved error. You can create your own iterable object be adding special property Symbol. iterator

{...null} - works because `typeof null == 'object'`, but in real life it doesn't make sense

Comment: Why should it work with `undefined` then? `{...undefined}` yields an empty object as well, afaik  `typeof undefined == 'undefined'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47155141/spreading-undefined-in-array-vs-object

Comment: So really the problem is that `...` is contextually different. Perhaps the article was misleading and it's not a special feature, just JS being JS