# Why Does Using the Spread Syntax Work with Primitives and Functions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2018

While testing some code, I came across some syntax I was not totally familiar with before:

```js
const obj = {
  key: "tree",
  value: "narra"
}

let condition = false;

var x = {...(condition && obj)};

console.log(x);
```

When I ran the code above I thought, I guess you can spread boolean values. But I tested on other primitive data as well such as integers and even on a function:

```js
let x = {...123};
console.log(x);

x = {...function(){}}
console.log(x)
```

I always thought that the spread syntax would only work on arrays, objects, & other iterables such as string and would otherwise cause syntax errors. Why does it work in my examples and why do they return void?

Comment: I hope this will be enough to clear your confusions https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-runtime-semantics-destructuringassignmentevaluation

Comment: That it works on booleans and functions is ok with me, but I don't get why it doesn't throw on `null` and  `undefined`... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47155141/spreading-undefined-in-array-vs-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object spread is just syntactic sugar for [`Object.assign`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-object.assign). `Object.assign` converts every source value to an object, just like what happens if you tried to access a property on a primitive value.

However, the objects created from primitives don't have **own** properties:

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(false));
```

(how could they, they are primitives after all (all their properties come from their prototype))

so it doesn't really have effects on the final result.

As for functions, `Object.assign` only considers *enumerable* properties and none of the default properties of a function is enumerable.