# Why object spread return type preserves allow undefined or null in TypeScipt?

Tags: typescript

The following example does not compile in TypeScript:

```js
function merge<A extends object | undefined | null, B extends object | undefined | null>(a: A, b: B): A & B & {} {
    return {
        ...a,
        ...b,
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
Type 'A & B' is not assignable to type 'A & B & {}'.
  Type 'A & B' is not assignable to type '{}'.(2322)
```

Is it a current limitation of TypeScript or my example is wrong?

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2&ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwKYCcDmqA8BBRVADylTABMBnROAIwCtVpEAfRcc1YGMVc1xGBAAbYQBpEAIUIkyVGgyZQBHLjz4ChogHwAKAIYAuRHgm1jkgJTGCAMimJ7AbwC+iJwChE3xOlRQQdCRPH1DEADpI-TEvMO9I8NoY0JcPVKA)

**Clarification:**

I know that `undefined & {}` or `null & {}` is `never`, so it will return also wrong results for "raw" `undefined` or `null` types, but `A & B & {}` will work better for nullable types than `A & B`.

I think that the more correct type should be `(A extends {} ? A : {}) & (B extends {} ? B : {})` but currently it does not work neither: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2&ssl=1&ssc=103&pln=1&pc=152#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwKYCcDmqA8BBRVADylTABMBnROAIwCtVpEAfRcc1YGMVc1xGBAAbYQBpEAIUIkyVGgyZQBHLjz4ChogHwAKAIYAuRHgm1jkgJTHdBYqQrUA3gF9EAfhOJjry4gBkiLrS9nLObp7SPi5+TgBQiImI6KhQIOhI8UnZiAB0+fpiCTmJ+bm0RdkucS5AA).

Comment: Can you explain why this was not the expected behavior?

Comment: @kelsny `{...undefined, ...undefined}` returns `{}`

Comment: Well, I meant as an edit to the post, but anyways, yes I believe this is a limitation of how TypeScript represents spreading merely as an intersection.

Comment: @kelsny *"I believe this is a limitation of how TypeScript..."* - maybe, but I am not sure, therefore I have asked. We have to wait until some TS guru will explain it to us (and maybe with a link to a TS issue).

Comment: ... If you wanted an accurate return type you would need something like this monstrosity: https://tsplay.dev/wEpp4W Even then, there might be some edge cases I have not caught (and I believe this could be shorter anyways).

Comment: The core problem is that for nullish values the intersection with object is `never`. Which makes a lot of sense type-wise `null & {}` is unsatisfiable. Well, actually the same as `null & undefined` - there is no value that can fit this. Which also describes the `A & B & {}` - there can be no value that satisfies this. It's  just not a valid to describe "at least empty object, maybe with some properties from A or B". Not really a bug or compiler limitation as much as "computers do what we tell them to, not what we want them to"

Comment: @VLAZ I know about that behavior. I have added clarification.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You don't want intersection, intersection means that the resulting object would be consist of the common fields of the base objects. So, anything intersecting with an empty object would lead to an object with no fields.</strike> You actually need second object overriding the fields of the first object.

Edit:

My first explanation was incorrect but still you don't want intersection since intersection of different property values lead to `never`, whereas it should just use the second object's type for that field.

```js
type MergeObjects<A extends object, B extends object> = {
  [K in (keyof A | keyof B)]: // Get all keys
      K extends keyof B // If B has the field use it
        ? B[K] 
        : K extends keyof A ? A[K] :never // If A has the field use it
}

type Merge<A extends object | null | undefined, B extends object | null | undefined> = A extends object 
  ? B extends object 
    ? MergeObjects<A, B> // A and B is object
    : A // only A is object
  : B extends object 
    ? B // only B is object
    : {} // neither are objects
```

Comment: "*anything intersecting with an empty object would lead to an object with no fields*" no,  `{}` as a type is just a lower bound. "at least no fields". Which is basically always true, thus in an intersection it will be "swallowed" by any other operands (as long as it's an object type): [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUBmB7dAuKA7ArgLYBGEATlAL4DcAUKJFAEIKxQBkyNtA9D1AIB6AfiA)

Comment: oh sorry, that one is a brain fart

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that if a or b is null or undefined, you expect the result to be undefined & null/undefined & B etc.
This can not work, the returned object is either undefined or null or an object but never two or more of them at the same time.
Therefor you have to sort out cases where a or b is undefined:

```
function merge<A extends object | undefined | null, B extends object | undefined | null>(a: A, b: B): A & B & {} {
        if (a && b) {
            return {
                ...a,
                ...b,
            };
        }
        throw new Error();
    }
```

Comment: Really? Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, it works for me in the typescript playground. Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: "*The problem is that you can not spread undefined or null.*" incorrect: https://jsbin.com/voxedegimi/1/edit?js,console See also: [Spreading undefined in array vs object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47155141)

Comment: @VLAZ right, I was imprecise in my formulation. I edited the post

Comment: The result is still clearly defined and it *would* be an object. Never an error. Error is clearly not expected as per the semantics of the spread operation. The result is *at least* an empty object or would be an object containing the combined properties of both parameters. Or the properties of one, if the other is nullish.

Comment: Intersecting the result with `Record<any, any>` will just be (effectively the same as) `Record<any, any>`.