Spread operator of undefined in object
Can someone please help find out if the behavior of this is defined in the JavaScript standard or just working by coincidence (yet still undefined behavior per the standard)?
{ ...undefined }

For instance:
const x = my?.property?.that?.does?.not?.exist // undefined
const y = { foo: 42, ...x }

I am aware of this question and the answers there, but the answers does not clarify whether this behavior is by design or UB.

The answer you linked to doesn't contain any links to authoratative sources that defines this construct as valid JavaScript, which is why I wrote "[...] can someone find out if this behavior is defined in the JavaScript standard [...]"? @0stone0

I just need to know if this is working by coincidence, but still UB (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

I don't see any mention of undefined in the MDN documentation. I tried looking in the EcmaScript specification, but it's inscrutible.

@mzedeler JavaScript has very little undefined behaviour. The example snippet you've shown is none of that, its semantics are clearly defined by the specification.

@Bergi can you link to the place in the specification where this behavior is defined? That would answer my question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47156824/476

I have written an answer to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78869530/800608
