# ES6 default parameters on a nullable nested object while destructuring

Tags: ecmascript-6, nested, destructuring, default-parameters, spread-syntax

I have an object like this

```
const obj = {
  foo: {
    bar: { // maybe null
      id: 0
    }
  }
};
```

I want to destructure `obj` to get `id`. If `bar` was only ever `undefined` or an object this would be sufficient:

```
const {
        foo: {
          bar: {
            id,
          } = {},
        } = {},
      } = obj;
```

But when `bar` is `null` I get the error `Cannot read property 'id' of null`.

I could do this, [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45210379/1469797)

```
const {
        foo: {
          bar = {},
        } = {},
      }      = obj;
const { id } = bar || {};
```

but this means I would need to destructure every nullable object as a separate statement, which I'd prefer not to do.

**Is there a way to make the default initializer for an object run if its value is null?**

Answer (score 3):

You can sort of "hijack" the spread operator. You'll have a not-so-beatiful syntax like but it works:

```
const obj = {
  foo: {
    bar: null
  }
}

const id = {...{...{...obj}.foo}.bar}.id
// id = undefined

You can add an "or something" to the end to get a default value, like:
const id = {...{...{...obj}.foo}.bar}.id || 42
// id = 42
```

The principle on how this works is that if you try to spread an undefined or null value, you'll get an empty object:

```
console.log('spreaded null', { ...null })
// {}

console.log('spreaded undefined', { ...undefined })
// {}
```

Now, if you access a property that isn't defined on an object, the JS engine will return you `undefined`, thus, you can spread it to have another empty object to chain the next inner property you need to access.

Comment: Yikes, its definitely not very readable. This also looks like I will still need a separate statement rather than being able to resolve it inside the original destructuring statement, right?